# Is there any option to use something similar to mockito argument captor?

Tags: unit-testing, go, mockito, gomock

we are using gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson to talk with mongo, and its API populates passed structures instead returning results, for example:

```
func (p *Pipe) One(result interface{}) error {...
```

Problems occurs when I want to mock / test code which is using that. I want to both mock this execution and somehow get pupulated value in 'result'.
Currently test has:

```
query.EXPECT().One(gomock.Any())
```

So as you can see I dont get any value, I just configure gomock to check that when I run my method then query.One has to be called.
I cannot pass structure like

```
mystruct := MyStruct{}
query.EXPECT().One(&mystruct)
```

because mystruct in test code and in real code is different and verifing mock will fail (references are different). Im looking for something similar to mockito's argument captor:
https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.9/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html

Answer (score 9):

This can be achieved via [Do](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/mock/gomock#Call.Do).

Copy & Paste of Github example from [poy](https://github.com/poy).

```
var capturedArgs []int

someMock.
  EXPECT().
  SomeMethod(gomock.Any()).
  Do(func(arg int){
    capturedArgs = append(capturedArgs, arg)
  })
```

Ref: https://github.com/golang/mock/pull/149

Answer (score 0):

This project can help you: https://github.com/bouk/monkey.
You can replace a function and use a bool variable to check the use.

```
called := false    
monkey.Patch(package.One, func(result interface{}) error {
    if result == expected {
       called := true
       return nil
    }
    return errors.new("not expected")
})
```

Dont't forget to restore your original function.

```
defer monkey.Unpatch(package.One)
```

Comment: unfortunately the author of this library does not give permission to use this tool for any purpose https://github.com/bouk/monkey/blob/master/LICENSE.md